# Remove only black dot in the image using opencv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I am posting to understand that is that possible to remove only black dot in the image.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is. Invert the image using `cv2.bitwise_not`, Then use `cv2.findContours()` to get all the fragments in the inverted image. Then filter out the smaller fragments based on area of the contour using `cv2.contourArea()`. Then re-draw the remaining contours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two methods:

**Method #1: Contour filtering**

We convert the image to grayscale, Otsu's threshold for a binary image, then find contours and filter using a minimum threshold area. We remove the black dots by drawing filling in the contours to effectively erase the dots

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 10:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

result = 255 - thresh
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Method #2: Morphological operations**

Similarly, we convert to grayscale then Otsu's threshold. From here we create a kernel and perform morph open

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
opening = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.waitKey()
```